# memory leakage when main is empty - Ubuntu/C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 image with VmWare,

I'm writing a program in C++ & whenever I check the memory with Valgrind,
I get a message that I have 1 alloc, with 0 free.
The thing is, that I noticed that it happens when **my main is empty**.

[image]

Now the interesting thing is, when I try it on a different version of Ubuntu (12), there are no allocs whatsoever.

Comment: This does answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know `iostream` has some global stuff which is initialized once you include this library. Also it is a known issue that STLs don't release their memory immediately.

Check this [link](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Valgrind/3.8.1/html/faq.html#faq.reports) about mem leakage on STL with valgrind.

Also this [link from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842123/5218277).